# How vim overwrites readonly mode?

Tags: shell, vim

Quite often we see that the file we are trying to save in vim after edit is reported to be read-only. The way around this is to add `!wq`, i am trying to figure out what internally goes that allows the vim program to gain enough permission to write the read-only file ?

Is there a internal flag which is switched or the vim temporarily gains the privileges for some time ?

Comment: “Quite often” (?) indicates that you might want to fix your file permissions. This should happen very rarely.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you do `w!` in Vim, what actually happens depends on who owns the file.

- If you (the current user) are the owner of the file, Vim will change the permissions to be writable before rewriting the file.  It then removes the write permissions to restore the permission bits to what it was from the start.
- If you are not the owner of the file, but if you have write permissions in the current directory, Vim will delete the original file and write the document to a new file with the same name.  The new file will then be assigned the same permissions as the original file, but will be owned by you.

At no time does Vim gain elevated privileges to be able to write to the file.

The mechanics described above are the available options that any program that needs to write to a read-only file has to choose from (i.e. either temporarily change the permission while writing to the file, or delete the file and create a new one), and what Vim ends up choosing to do may in the end may depend on a number of configurable settings.

As seen in comments below, there is some confusion about the above.  If you want to see for yourself what actually happens with your setup of Vim on your particular brand of Unix, I'd recommend tracing the system calls that Vim does while writing to a read-only file.  How this is done depends on what Unix you are using.  On Linux, this is likely done through e.g. `strace vim file` (then editing the file, saving it with `w!` and exiting).

---

This is the first case (output from `ktrace`+`kdump` on OpenBSD):

```
13228 vim      CALL  chmod(0x19b1d94b4b10,0100644<S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH|S_IFREG>)
13228 vim      NAMI  "file"
13228 vim      RET   chmod 0
13228 vim      CALL  lseek(3,0x1000,SEEK_SET)
13228 vim      RET   lseek 4096/0x1000
13228 vim      CALL  write(3,0x19b1e0aa9000,0x1000)
```

This changes permissions on the file so that it's writable (the `S_IWUSR` flag used with `chmod()`) and writes the buffer to it.

It then sets the original permissions:

```
13228 vim      CALL  fchmod(4,0100444<S_IRUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH|S_IFREG>)
13228 vim      RET   fchmod 0
13228 vim      CALL  close(4)
13228 vim      RET   close 0
```

For the other case:

It first unlinks (deletes) the file and then recreates it (before writing to the file and changing permissions later):

```
44487 vim      CALL  unlink(0x79fdbc1f000)
44487 vim      NAMI  "file"
44487 vim      RET   unlink 0
44487 vim      CALL  open(0x79fdbc1f000,0x201<O_WRONLY|O_CREAT>,0644<S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH>)
44487 vim      NAMI  "file"
44487 vim      RET   open 4
```

Comment: It's really odd that you would get different results (even on a different OS) for the same software.  Could you confirm the version you are using and the value of the two relavent config options you mention (`backup` and `backupcopy`)

Comment: @PhilipCouling Vim 8.1.800. Both `backup` and `backupcopy` are unset (this is _without_ a private `.vimrc` file).

Comment: Likewise neither of mine are set in config and `8.1.800` is very close to `8.1.875`, could you also confirm the result of `set backup?` and `set backupcopy?` It's plausible the good people at Debian compiled in something different.

Comment: I did a `truss` on FreeBSD of both VIM and NeoVIM.  I even checked nvi for good measure.  I duplicated Kusalananda's results with all three.

Comment: @JdeBP Yes I'm rapidly becoming suspicious I'm seeing something unusual or Debian specific.

Comment: I'm disappointed vim actually implements this. I'm used to w! being used to overrride -R.

Comment: There's a VIM script file on the FreeBSD system claiming that it was written by Bram Moolenaar, that sets `nowritebackup`.  I am having difficulty tracking down the provenance of this file.  On OpenBSD, no such scripts exist at all.  Creating a blank `~/.vimrc` yields `writebackup` set, and _does not_ reproduce Kusalananda's results under `ktrace`.

Comment: @JdeBP Which of the results, that of changing the permission before writing? I've just tested this again with an empty `.vimrc` as well as with no `.vimrc` file on OpenBSD-current and I still see the `chmod()` call and no `unlink()`.

Comment: @JdeBP Additionally, if the file has a hard link, that link is not severed when saving the file (which is possible only if the file had its permission temporarily altered). In the case when the file is owned by another user _and_ there's a hard link, the `w!` command will _fail_ with an `E166` error ("Can't open linked file for writing").  See `:he E166` in Vim for further info about that.

Comment: I get @PhilipCouling's results when testing Vim 8.0.1298 on Gentoo.

Comment: The second result is rather surprising to me. I would not expect my text editor to change the ownership of a file I've modified. +1 for explaining this.

Answer (score 5):

Vim cannot gain additional permissions. The `:w!` just overrides the internal `'readonly'` option, which may have been set because:

- you've opened the file via the `-R` command-line option or with `:view` instead of `:edit`, or `:setlocal readonly`
- Vim recognizes that the file currently doesn't have write permissions

For the latter case, a file write may still be possible because Vim (by default) *creates a new file* and then replaces the original file with it. That still depends on the permissions being set in a way to allow this.

---

To really gain write permissions where the user that opened Vim doesn't have any, the `:w !sudo tee >/dev/null file` trick has to be used, either directly, or through a plugin like [SudoEdit](https://github.com/chrisbra/SudoEdit.vim).

Answer (score 2):

You can't ever write to a file that you don't have write permissions on.  However you can delete that file if you have write permissions on the directory.

The trick that VIM is using is to delete the file and write a new one.

It's possible to show this is the method VIM uses without reading source code by checking the [inode number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) before and after:

```
$ touch foo
$ chmod u-w foo
$ ls -li foo
60818465 -r--r----- 1 philip philip 0 Feb 25 10:24 foo
$ vi foo
$ # edit the file and save with :w!
$ ls -li foo
60818467 -r--r----- 1 philip philip 8 Feb 25 10:25 foo
```

Note that the inode number changed showing that the new file is NOT the same file as the one you edited.

---

FYI My current config is really short:

```
runtime! debian.vim
if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif
set tabstop=4
set autoindent
```

And debian packages installed are:

```
vim                               2:8.1.0875-1
vim-common                        2:8.1.0875-1
vim-runtime                       2:8.1.0875-1
vim-tiny                          2:8.1.0875-1
```

Comment: Changing permissions on the file is _exactly_ what Vim does, at least on OpenBSD.

Comment: @Kusalananda as per the experement above, not in Debian with `Vim 2:8.1.0875-1`.  The file is clearly being completely replaced.

Comment: This is not the method that VIM uses by default.  The doco (`:help :write`) states that it temporarily changes permissions, and a quick `truss` confirms that the doco is right.  You have non-default backup options set.

Comment: The phrase "by default" means "what happens if not otherwise configired" no?  And `:set backupcopy?` results in `backupcopy=auto`.  I've checked my config. There's nothing in there to change this behaviour (I think?)

Comment: when `vim` is in compatible mode, `:w!` will only override the read-only mode of the buffer, but will not try to change the file perms back and forth or do other amateur hour stuff. This is the only right behavior -- it would be nice if it was clearly mentioned which one of the options turned on or off by `:set compatible` is responsible for this.

Comment: If that were actually true, mosvy, the i-node number would not be changing.

Comment: There's nothing obvious in Debian's patches to affect this.

Comment: It's `writebackup` but I haven't fully determined how.

Comment: @JdeBP This is strange. `writebackup` is enabled by default in debian.  Looking at the source, that's correct for version `8.1.0800` too.  If the feature exists, its enabled https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/4456ab527a6a5faae9287f3bd2e52cc18966cfb0/src/version.c#L734 .  Though I've not had enough time to check this.  Is it possible the good fellows at BSD have configured something?

Comment: @JdeBP It seems that we're talking about different things; I've added an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/502958/308316) which identifies `:set cpo+=W` as the option to turn on if you don't want `vim` to do dangerous stupid stuff behind your back. Don't know if anybody else's interested, though.

Answer (score 2):

When vim is in vi-compatible mode, :w! will only override the read-only mode of the buffer, but will not try to change the file permissions back and forth, bypass permissions by renaming a different file to the name of the original, or do other amateur hour stuff.

This is the only right behavior IMHO -- the flag which controls this is `W` from `cpoptions` / `cpo`. From `:help cpo`:

> ```
>                                                 *'cpoptions'* *'cpo'* *cpo*
> 'cpoptions' 'cpo'       string  (Vim default: "aABceFs",
>                                  Vi default:  all flags)
> ...
>                                                                 *cpo-W*
>                 W       Don't overwrite a readonly file.  When omitted, ":w!"
>                         overwrites a readonly file, if possible.
> ```

`:set compatible` will turn all `cpo` flags on. You can change just the `W` flag with `:set cpo+=W` or `set cpo-=W`.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the actual question that is being asked, however, which is how VIM does things when it _does_ override file permissions.

Comment: @JdeBP I know, but since I've spent time researching it (when I have to use `vim` I always `set compatible` as a matter of course and don't bother to learn anything beyond that), I might've just as well put it in an answer. Feel free to downvote/flag/ignore. If you want to know what `vim` is actually doing when `:w!`, you can have a look at `buf_write()` in `src/fileio.c` and `do_write()` in `src/ex_cmds.c`.